# mod rewrite stops at the & , so pages named 'Britain-&-Ireland.php' aren't found

Tags: php, mysql, apache

So my rewrite rule sends request for

www.cruiseandmaritime.com/cruises/French-Leave.php to

www.cruiseandmaritime.com/cruise_details_by_name.php?id=French-Leave

which works fine

```
RewriteRule ^cruises/([a-zA-Z0-9-&]+).php?$ cruise_details_by_name.php?id=$1    [NC,L]  # Handle requests for all cruises
```

However , some of the cruises use the ampersand in their title... (British & Northern Isles) so they would be

www.cruiseandmaritime.com/cruises/British-&-Northern-Isles.php

and that does not work because my query looks up the cruise by name and the only bit that is passed to my get variable is "British" there's nothing else after the & and no &

So I'm confused...

Rich :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
www.cruiseandmaritime.com/cruises/British-&-Northern-Isles.php
```

is not a valid URL, as the `&` is not supposed to be there. From there its just a case of rubbish in is rubbish out :)

an ampersand in an url should be `%26`

Comment: right, I see it now. for nice search friendly url's I should get them to use the word 'and' shouldn't I really anyway

Comment: You might even want to drop that `and`, but that's probably a discussable point :)

Answer (score 0):

You regex is weird. What do you suppose `-&` would mean?

I wouldt think it should be somethin like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\&]
```

Comment: that's what I thought, I tried that, don't forget I'm allowing the hypen character '-'.

Comment: @Rich, ok, but I would think that you have to escape the hyphen (with a backslash in front of it) since the hyphen has special meaning in regexes (your own example already uses hyphens, eg. `a-z`).

Comment: escaping the hyphen and ampersand is correct I see now @mjastzebowski is on to something here , my variable is split up...

Answer (score 0):

I try this on http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ and don't exactly know why, but rules which is working:

```
([&a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
```

Comment: It's working as mod_rewrite rule, but I don't think that url like: cruise_details_by_name.php?id=British-&-Northern-Isles is right (now You have var $id='British-' and empty var $-Northern-Isles which is all wrong... ;- )

Comment: yes that's where I think I'm wrong.. ah hah... a url id = something & something would make two variables of course... so how do I get around that ?

Comment: You can excape ampersand with %26 code, but I think You should just change the title to something like this: cruises/British-Northern-Isles.php or better cruises/British-and-Northern-Isles.php